# iOS upgrading issue

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App Crashing after iOS upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680981/app-crashing-after-ios-upgrade)

I upgraded my device from iOS 5.1.0 to iOS 5.1.1. 
After up gradation my app were crashing on clicking the app icon. What can be the possible reasons for this?

I am using the following storage in my app.
- Using NSUserDefaults to read value from at app launch.
- Using keychain to store user credentials.
- Does User defaults and Keychain gets affected while iOS up gradation.

Comment: You need to check the  crash logs to check exactly what happens?

Comment: you can paste those logs here as well, so that we can get the idea what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because Apple changed the internal structure of the views. I have seen this when you loop through the subview and Apple made any significant changes to the view all that code is not going to work. Something similar is happening in your case.

This is what I would do, run application on your phone from xcode and keep breakpoints on, it should help you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Deleting the app and reinstalling it again on the upgraded device resolves the issue. If the view structure is changed then it should crash after installing a fresh copy of the app.